# How does localhost get fed into {host} and "1234" gets fed into {id}

Tags: resteasy

Can someone explain to me how "localhost" will be fed into {host} and "1234" will be fed into {id} ?

QUOTE:

The Link.Builder has an underlying UriBuilder. The values passed into the build()
method are passed along to this UriBuilder to create the URI for the Link. Let’s look
at an example:

```
   Link link = Link.fromUri("http://{host}/root/customers/{id}")
                   .rel("update").type("text/plain")
                   .build("localhost", "1234");
```

Calling toString() on the link instance will result in:

```
<http://localhost/root/customers/1234>; rel="update"; type="text/plain"
```

END QUOTE

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**UriBuilder** also introduces a set of methods that provide ways of resolving URI templates by replacing individual templates with a provided value(s).

```
final URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://{host}/{path}?q={param}")
    .resolveTemplate("host", "localhost")
    .resolveTemplate("path", "myApp")
    .resolveTemplate("param", "value").build();

uri.toString(); // returns "http://localhost/myApp?q=value"
```

Comment: but the author never used any sort of resolution, so I'm lost as to how host gets localhost etc.  I mean, for all I know, host could have been 1234 and id could have been localhost.